# OCR recognition improvement

Tags: opencv, ocr, tesseract, image-recognition, torch

I’m working with tesseract on some recognition on some video streams. i need assistance improving and also maybe looking at other image recognition libraries. I have a number of streams that have different elements in them, so each have to be designed for recognition differently.

So the current streams are over twitch. 1 of the issues is that sometimes twitch streams in different quality - I have 720p, 480p, 360p. what i need to know is the winning team and the score.

main issue atm is that tesseract cannot recognise characters or font on a image from a 360p stream. here is the sample image...

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=9hm4vp&s=8#.Vi95xxDhCSM

And here's some more 360p quality images in a drive...

http://1drv.ms/1M1O75J

So yeah thats my issue, mainly how to recognise the text well on a 360p image :) i have no idea of best method or libraries so any help would be great :)